# Why my DirectoryInfo.GetFiles return 0 results although the folder if full

Tags: c#, .net

i try to take 5 newest files from my `Directory`:

```
string folder = @"C:\temp";

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
var files = dir.GetFiles()
         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).Take(5);
```

And this return 0 result  although  the folder if full f files.

UPDATE:

```
private static List<string> _folders;
public delegate void OnFileAddDelegate(FileInfo[] files);
public event OnFileAddDelegate OnFileAddEventHandler;

public void SearchFiles()
{
    foreach (string folder in _folders)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            var files = dir.GetFiles()
                     .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).Take(5).ToArray();

            foreach (var item in files)
                OnFileAddEventHandler(files);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently my problem is that i am looking for the newest 5 files but if only 1 file exist in return more than 1 (same file twice)

Comment: Does the account you're running your code under have access to the files?

Comment: Yes and the path is valid

Comment: What is "0 result"? How do you check it?

Comment: Try to call `.Take(5).ToArray();`

Comment: i have checked files

Comment: Take(5).ToArray() works fine.

Comment: I would assert that either `files` has a count of greater than 0, you have a permissions issue, or your folder isn't "full". (I don't know how you fill a folder anyway). I don't know of any other scenario here.

Comment: `Take(5).ToArray() ` if this works fine, post the code how you read files from `files` variable

Comment: yeah, could you have iterated over the enumerable twice?

Comment: does your directory contain any sub-directories? if so try dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)...

Comment: Why iterated twice ?

Comment: How did you get `0` result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your Handler passing it ALL files while enumerating EACH file (you're not passing item but files, so if you have 10 times you're saying, 10 times, pass the whole list)

What you're doing :

```
        foreach (var item in files)
            OnFileAddEventHandler(files);
```

What you probably want to do

```
        OnFileAddEventHandler(files);
```

Or if it takes single files

```
        foreach (var item in files)
            OnFileAddEventHandler(item);
```